# greek and superscripts and variable values in R plot label

Tags: r, data-visualization

sorry I know this might involve expression and paste but I've spent ages not getting this right
I need sigma^2=a variable value as a title in R
you can see these efforts don't work

```
val<-2 
plot(1:10,main=paste(expression("sigma^2"),"=",val))
plot(1:10,main=expression(paste("sigma^2"),"=",val))
```

many thanks for any advie from wise gurus

Comment: thanks Stephane but I may have tried that before - when I do that it ignores the =2 part I want after - I just get the sigma squared

Comment: Try plot(1:10, main = bquote(sigma^2==.(val))) or 
plot(1:10, main = substitute(sigma^2==A, list(A = val)))

Comment: no probs Stephane, your reply was still helpful, I need to understand betterall this paste, expression,substitute stuff, I'lll read that other post too - thanks again